# Performance of a singleton instance OkHttpClient

Tags: android, okhttp

I'm using `OkHttp` at the first time. I see the tutorial said that If wanna use `Response Caching`, I must call `new OkHttpClient()` **exactly once** (a singleton instance). `OkhttpClient` is thread-safe by `synchronized` methods. But in my application, there are many threads connects to the network to get remote data simultaneously, some threads must wait for a thread have done getting data to execute its operation.
So Is it's performance not better than normal?
If yes, If I don't enable `Reponse Caching`, should I call `new OkHttpClient()` **many times** for better performance?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the best performance, share a single `OkHttpClient` instance. This allows your cache to be shared, and in the future when we implement [fancy joining & cancelling](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/607) it’ll allow outgoing requests to be merged.